# R: rvest extracting innerHTML

Tags: r, web-scraping, innerhtml, tostring, rvest

Using **rvest** in R to scrape a web-page, I'd like to **extract the equivalent of `innerHTML` from a node**, in particular to change line-breaks into newlines before applying `html_text`.

Example of desired functionality:

```
library(rvest)
doc <- read_html('<html><p class="pp">First Line<br />Second Line</p>')
innerHTML(doc, ".pp")
```

Shall produce following output:

```
[1] "<p class=\"pp\">First Line<br>Second Line</p>"
```

With `rvest 0.2` this can be achieved through **`toString.XMLNode`**

```
# run under rvest 0.2
library(XML)
html('<html><p class="pp">First Line<br />Second Line</p>') %>% 
  html_node(".pp") %>% 
  toString.XMLNode
[1] "<p class=\"pp\">First Line<br>Second Line</p>"
```

With the newer `rvest 0.2.0.900` this does not work anymore.

```
# run under rvest 0.2.0.900
library(XML)
html_node(doc,".pp") %>% 
  toString.XMLNode
[1] "{xml_node}\n<p>\n[1] <br/>"
```

The desired functionality is generally available in the **`write_xml`** function of package `xml2` on which `rvest` now depends - if only `write_xml` could give its output to a variable instead of insisting to write to a file. (also a `textConnection` is not accepted).

As a *workaround* I can temporarily write to a file:

```
# extract innerHTML, workaround: write/read to/from temp file
html_innerHTML <- function(x, css, xpath) {
  file <- tempfile()
  html_node(x,css) %>% write_xml(file)
  txt <- readLines(file, warn=FALSE)
  unlink(file)
  txt
}
html_innerHTML(doc, ".pp") 
[1] "<p class=\"pp\">First Line<br>Second Line</p>"
```

with this I can then for example transform the line break tags into new-line characters:

```
html_innerHTML(doc, ".pp") %>% 
  gsub("<br\\s*/?\\s*>","\n", .) %>%
  read_html %>%
  html_text
[1] "First Line\nSecond Line"
```

Is there a better way to do this with existing functions from e.g. `rvest`, `xml2`, `XML` or other packages? In particular I'd like to avoid to write to the hard disk.

Comment: Seems like filing an issue on github might be more productive...

Comment: For follow-up, this was added as an issue and [eventually resolved](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/87). The answer is simply to use `as.character`.

Answer (score 2):

As @r2evans noted, `as.character(doc)` is the solution.

Regarding you last code snippet, which wants to extract the `<br>`-separated text out of the node while converting `<br>` to newline, there is a workaround in the currently unresolved [rvest issue #175, comment #2](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/175#issuecomment-266434812):

The simplified version for this problem:

```
doc <- read_html('<html><p class="pp">First Line<br />Second Line</p>')

# r2evan's solution:
as.character(rvest::html_node(doc, xpath="//p"))
##[1] "<p class=\"pp\">First Line<br>Second Line</p>"

# rentrop@github's solution, simplified:
innerHTML <- function(x, trim = FALSE, collapse = "\n"){
    paste(xml2::xml_find_all(x, ".//text()"), collapse = collapse)
}
innerHTML(doc)
## [1] "First Line\nSecond Line"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution using `rvest` 0.3.5:

```r
doc <- xml2::read_html('<html><p class="pp">First Line<br />Second Line</p>')

nodes <- rvest::html_nodes(doc, css = '.pp')
# {xml_nodeset (1)}
# [1] <p class="pp">First Line<br>Second Line</p>

rvest::html_text(nodes)
# [1] "First LineSecond Line"
```

Comment: This misses the question, which wasn't to get the node's text, but to be able to get the text with the linebreak accounted for