# Extracting innerHTML using rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

I would like to extract the html content of a tag in R. For instance, in the following HTML,

```
<html><body>Hi <b>name</b></body></html>
```

suppose I'd like to extract the content of the `<body>` tag, which would be:

```
Hi <b>name</b>
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129407/r-rvest-extracting-innerhtml) question, the answer (using `as.character()`) will include the enclosing tag, which is *not* what I want. eg,

```
library(rvest)
html = '<html><body>Hi <b>name</b></body></html>'
read_html(html) |>
    html_element('body') |>
    as.character()
```

returns outerHTML:

```
[1] "<body>Hi <b>name</b>\n</body>"
```

...but I want the innerHTML. How can I get the content of a HTML tag in R, without the enclosing tag?

Comment: Do you only want the text? `read_html(html) |> html_element('body') |>  html_text()`

Comment: That will remove the <b> tags in my example. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an inbuilt function to do this so here's a custom one.

```
library(rvest)

html = '<html><body>Hi <b>name</b></body></html>'

turn_to_character_keeping_inner_tags <- function(x, tag) {
  gsub(sprintf('^<%s.*?>|</%s>$', tag, tag), '', as.character(x))
}

read_html(html) |> 
  html_element('body') |> 
  turn_to_character_keeping_inner_tags('body')

[1] "Hi <b>name</b>\n"
```

Comment: Is this guaranteed to work, eg, when there are attributes? The opening body tag: "<body style='color: red'>" would throw this code off.

Comment: You are right. The updated answer should take care of that. I also added another condition to remove the tag from only the beginning and end so in case you have the same tag in inner HTML that would still remain. @richarddmorey

Comment: Isn't "< body>" (note space after opening "<") a valid body tag that will be missed by this?